# Dealing with C's Null terminating pointer (ffi)

Tags: c, rust

I remember there being a function `array_each` but that's now deprecated. Was this replaced with another function? If not, how can I use the C pointer to an array as a rust array?

```
extern {
  fn testing() -> *MyList
}

#[repr(C)]
struct MyList;

fn main() {
  unsafe {
    let list = testing();
    // would like to iterate through the list here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::slice::from_raw_parts`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html):

```
extern {
    fn get_some_list(len: *mut u32) -> *mut u32;
}

fn main() {
    use std::slice;
    unsafe {
        let mut len: u32 = 0;
        let ptr: *mut u32 = get_some_list(&mut len);
        assert!(!ptr.is_null());
        let view: &[u32] = slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, len as usize);
        for &v in view.iter() { println!("{}", v); }
    }
}
```

The resulting slice may have an arbitrary lifetime (including `'static`), so be careful about exposing that slice to the safe outside.

(Note: Your original code uses some old syntax, which I've fixed in this answer. For example, you need `const` or `mut` after `*` now.)

Comment: std::c_vec::CVec No longer exists :-(

Comment: @ferrouswheel Updated! c_vec was removed by RFC 494, FYI.